# Adding a watermark image to a video or a stream is not working

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I'm trying to add a logo to a video and a stream with FFmpeg.

For the video I'm using

```
ffmpeg –i viddeo.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" bottom_left.mp4
```

but I get this error:

> Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter
>   Parsed_overlay_0

For the stream, using this

```
ffmpeg -re -i http://server.com/live.m3u8 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 1500k -f flv rtmp://test:1935/live/kky4zhl
```

leads to this error:

> Streamcopy requested for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a
>   complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.

Neither are working. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In stream command, change `-c:v copy` to `-c:v libx264`. For first command, share full log.